# Android Gridview setOnitemClicklisterner no function in alert dialog

Tags: android, gridview, android-alertdialog

i have a problem in my gridview, i insert my gridview in my alertbox, but the function for my setOnitemClicklistener is not working in my alertbox. How to implment setOnitemClicklistener in alertbox for the gridview. Any suggestion for this problem

```
 LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
             View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompt_quantity, null);
             final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
             // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
             alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
             final GridView modifiergridview = (GridView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.modifiergridview);
             modifierList = db.getModifierName(pName);
             modifiergridview.setAdapter(new Modifierlist());

             modifiergridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
             @Override
                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
              });


              alertDialog.show();
              alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(2000, 2000);



       }
 });
```

**Modifierlist.java**

```
 public class Modifierlist extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public ArrayList<Integer> getPositions() {
        return positions;
    }

    public Modifierlist() {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return modifierList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.modifierlistview, null);
        }
        modifiername = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modifierbutton);

        Modifier myObj = modifierList.get(position);
        modifiername.setText("" + myObj.getModifierName());


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste Modifierlist() class code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set onclicklistener on modifiername in adapter class

```
    modifiername.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: but basically i use setOnitemClicklistener for my gridview it work well

Comment: why there is the problem gridview in alertbox?

Answer (score 0):

Use Dialog **instead of** AlertDialog.Builder.

Comment: thanks, i use AlertDialog.Builder because i want to prompt up with my xml design layout

Comment: you can also use you xml design in Dialog  just add **dialog.setView(R.layout.dialog_layout);**